# ChrootDirectory Path Not Working for AD User

Tags: sftp

I am setting up a SFTP in the Domain Controller server. I have edited the sshd_config file and set the ChrootDirectory to the path C:\Incoming as I am following the [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eklxg_UUktI). Every time I SFTP I get directed to C:\User\Jane.Doe instead. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
# override default of no subsystems Subsystem sftp sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User jane.doe
      ChrootDirectory C:\Incoming
```